# Numerically solving a system of linear ODEs with different time conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, programming

I am interested in solving the following system of ODEs numerically
\begin{align}
x'=2x+3y+z\\
y'=x-3y+2z\\
z'=x+2y-4z
\end{align}
with conditions at **distinct** times, even at time at **infinity**.
\begin{align}
x(0)=1, y(0)=1, z(+\infty)=0
\end{align}

Can I use PYTHON or MATLAB to solve it? If yes, where I can find such tutorial? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess that "$z(+\infty)$"should be $\lim\limits_{t\to + \infty}z(t)=0$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo yes, exactly!

Comment: @user10354138 thank you, it is my typo, I fixed it.

Comment: Use the shooting method(s) to solve for $z(0)$.  There are enough tutorials out there about this (with the caveat about limit doesn't necessarily allow application of IVT in general, but in this case we know the exact solution).

Comment: @user10354138 many thanks I gonna check it right now!

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66531775/how-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-odes-with-distinct-time-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linear system, you can solve it via eigen-decomposition. This produces a positive and two negative eigenvalues. The solution has to lie in the eigenspaces of the negative eigenvalues. This gives the missing initial condition as
$$
z(0)=-5.024155419109322.
$$
Long-term numerical simulation with this initial condition will likely not converge to zero in all components, as numerical errors will build up some small coefficient for the component with a positive eigenvalue, which will then grow exponentially.

$$
(λ_1,λ_2,λ_3)=( 2.93491425,\, -2.40143568,\, -5.53347857),
\\
V=(v_1,v_2,v_3)=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.95198356& 0.56546078&  0.16012843\\
 0.2289107& -0.66866328& -0.64979254\\
 0.2032909 & -0.48284938&  0.74305352
\end{bmatrix}\\
(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(0.0,\,3.11077114,\, -4.74006433)
\\
y(t)=\sum_{k=1}^3c_cv_ke^{λ_kt}
$$

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!